# Node js mongodb, mongoose find multiple items

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

So I wanna find multiple items so I don't have to loop sense I was told not to do that.

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59d2b1cf8cec1709f85eb7a9"), "title" : "Arrow", "common_movies" : [ ], "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59d2b1cf8cec1709f85eb7aa"), "title" : "Gotham", "common_movies" : [ ], "__v" : 0 }
```

my database's movie collection looks like this.
and I want an array with 2 items in it, the Arrow and Gotham objects, This is what I tried

```
Movie.find({title: "Arrow"}, {title: "Gotham"}, function(err, foundMovie){
    console.log(foundMovie)
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to select movies where name is Arrow or Gotham, then you should use `or` operator in your criteria object: `var criteria = { $or: [ {title: 'Arrow'}, {title: 'Gotham'} ]}`. See [mongodb documentation about OR logical operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/#op._S_or).

Then use criteria object in your `find` method:

```
Movie.find(criteria, function(err, foundMovie){
    console.log(foundMovie)
});
```

Comment: @KeeganRiley, If this is right answer, please accept it.